# How do I fix elementor section?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I got a big problem... I am using drawattention and everything was fine untill suddenly the sections are broken, I believe it got something to do with elementor...

When I enter the elementor editor, it looks great and then on preview its broken.
And when u go to inspect page it gets fixed.

How do I fix this?

Website:
https://plgrupa.hr/projekti/projekt-harambasiceva/stanovi-harambasiceva-57/

Thanks in advance!

I tryed changing CSS in many ways and nothing helped...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just discovered that if content in elementor is stretched to full width it gets broken... Boxed content is good

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it has something to to with other plugins you have installed. I recommend you to first deactivate all the plugins and activate them one by one to find out which one is interfering with elementor. It's regular that often plugins are not working together well and may break.
If it has nothing to do with other plugins, than you should start searching the errors in code.